# Random SQL Drops

Tags: sql, connection

Am seeing an intermittent issue with a production SQL box, with errors returning:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Running perfmon shows me that there are a maximum of 15 user connections open - on many occassions we open much more than this in the past.  So i think this rules out connections that are left open.
Furthermore this is a production application that has not undergone changes over the past couple of months, and has always run perfectly well.

I am thinking maybe DNS issues, or siwtch issues possibly, as the web and SQL boxes are running on the same network, without firewalls in between.

Can anybody else shed any light.

One another note - the reference to "provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server" - i assume this denotes a connection via named pipes.  I actually disabled named pipes earlier in an attempt to force TCP?

Comment: I've experienced this error many times and it was rarely (never?) a network issue. Use SQL Profiler to try to work out what's happening when the error occurs. Most times I found SQL Server was simply too busy to create a new connection. The most recent occasion another connection was INSERTing tens of thousands of rows.

Comment: Hi, sorry i should of close this off, but it was related to a VMWARE snapshot issue in the end.  Thanks for the advice anyway.